# What does the file status " A" mean in git?

Tags: git

Typically for untracked files the git status is "??".  Somehow I managed to
get:

```
$ git status --porcelain
 A deps/tree_sitter-0.20.4.dist-info/METADATA
 ...
A  src/test.py
 M src/utils.py
```

For illustration, I changed a tracked file " M src/utils.py", and I staged a
previously untracked file "A  src/test.py".

But I don't know what " A deps/tree_sitter-0.20.4.dist-info/METADATA" means.
It has been *added* to the working dir but is unchanged but known in the index.

git status not-porcelain says

```
Changes not staged for commit:
     new file:   deps/tree_sitter-0.20.4.dist-info/METADATA
```

So it is a change but also a new file.  What am I missing at the moment?

The question was marked as a duplicate but the linked duplicate asks for the broad explanation of git statuses.  Here I ask for the very specific, very seldom file status " A".  I state in the question that I know what this means technically but still I don't know how I got there and what the semantics are.

**To put it the other way around.  We know that git marks unknown files, aka untracked ones, with "??".  Now, how can there be a *new* file ("A") in the working dir which is at the same time unchanged (" "), thus known, in the index?**

Comment: I feel like there is something you are not revealing. Are you in the middle of a merge?

Comment: No I'm not in a merge.  I actually fast-forwarded from the remote repo.

Comment: you might have did: `git add *` and your .gitignore does not include a rule for *.dist-info/*

Comment: What did the remote repo do to `deps/tree_sitter-0.20.4.dist-info/METADATA`? I think you can just diff between HEAD and where you were before the merge (fast-forward) in order to find out.

Comment: I since asking learned that `add --intent-to-add` set such a file status, i.e. " A".  But I did not do this here.  So a) I don't know how to reproduce this for a test case and b) I lack understanding its meaning.  I could easily still interpret " A" as: a new, untracked file.  It seems that for me new and untracked are synonymous, but for git obviosuly not.

Answer (score -1):

In git status

```
A means the file is being added.
M modified
Green color staged 
U untracked
D deleted
```

Comment: "U" is not untracked.  Untracked files are "??".  But the question is also about file status pairs.  How can there be a *new* file ("A") in the working dir which is at the same time unchanged (" "), thus known,  in the index?